# How to use aspectj-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

I'm a newbie to AspectJ and Maven.

I'm trying to use aspectj-maven-plugin to build my project, but it does not work. I just followed the steps in *AspectJ In Action 2<sup>nd</sup> Edition*.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.5</source>
                        <target>1.5</target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here's the error message I get on the `<execution>` line:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:compile (execution: default, phase: compile)

I'm using JDK6 and Apache Maven 3.0.4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install the AspectJ Maven configurator.　It is available here:

http://dist.springsource.org/release/AJDT/configurator/

Help -> Install new software...

Add this update site to the "work with" section and select the feature.

Comment: Eclipse gives me a "required item could not be found" error when I try to use that update site.

Comment: @LordTorgamus Do you have the full error?  Make sure that AJDT is already installed.

Comment: Not offhand... I'll get back to you in 8-12 hours.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I switched from STS to clean Eclipse and had this error. Installing this configurator solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this plugin execution issue with aspectj-maven-plugin, you can wrap your  tag with  tag in your pom.xml. This will remove the exception in eclipse.

Shown as below:

```
<build>
    ....
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> ... </plugin>
             ....
             ....
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why this works though, but it does. See [Plugin Management in Maven](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-plugin-management) (Baeldung) and [pluginManagement in the Maven POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#plugin-management).

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this :

```
<executionManger><execution>...<execution/><executionManger/>
```

it will be working