# AJDT on Eclipse/Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, ajdt

I cloned and imported a github project as a maven project into Eclipse Juno.

I am getting the following error in pom.xml:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile (execution: default, phase: process-sources)
```

The property org.aspectj-version:1.6.10 is defined in pom.xml.

AJDT for Juno is installed on my machine.

What am I missing ?

I am new to Maven.

I saw [How to use aspectj-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514599/how-to-use-aspectj-maven-plugin/14571917#14571917) and some other discussions.

Note: I tried running the code by invoking maven on Tomcat 7. It's getting hung at:

```
Jul 23, 2013 12:46:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstracyProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

//=============================

EDIT: Starting out as Dynamic web prj & converting into a Maven one, all from scratch. nothing else seemed to work.

//=============================

In Preferences > Maven > Templates, I am seeing "AspectJ plugin" with the description "AspectJ plugin configuration" listed as "on" under the column "Auto Insert".

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the aspectj configurator for m2e. I think it is available in Preferences -> Maven -> Discovery.

---

**EDIT** That's surprising that you are not seeing the configurator in the discovery page. Perhaps it was removed recently.  Anyway, you can install it directly from this update site:

http://dist.springsource.org/release/AJDT/configurator/

Comment: Preferences -> Maven -> Discovery isn't giving me anything related to aspectj.

Comment: Please also see my second edit. spent time at Prefs > Maven while at it. :)